# How to generate wadl for jax-rs cxf

Tags: rest, dependency-injection, cxf, jax-rs, wadl

I need to generate wadl file for dynamic sub resource. Is it possible?
Iam using an interface as sub resource and its implementation does the actual work.
Iam using dependency injection to call the API. But I dont know how to generate wadl file for it. When I do this `http://localhost:8080/myfashions/catalog/product?_wadl&_type=xml`, I get

```
<resource path="/">
<!--  Dynamic subresource  -->
<resource path="/"/>
```

Can anyone help me, how to get wadl for Dynamic subresource.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate Wadl for apache cxf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006119/generate-wadl-for-apache-cxf)

Answer (score 0):

You must at least call your dynamic resource **once**, in order to be included into generated wadl.

hope that help.

best regards