# Generate Wadl for apache cxf

Tags: cxf, wadl

Is there any way to automatically generate wadl file for cxf?
Iam having a class that takes all requests like @Path("/") and then redirect to its implementation class. I want to generate wadl for it. Is this possible?
I have done this http://{localhost}:8080/api/?_wadl but Iam getting

```
<resources base="http://{localhost}:8080/api">
    <resource path="/">
        <!--  Dynamic subresource  -->
        <resource path="/"/>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is possible. What you did is dynamic, cxf doesn't know where the request will be directed to. Make sure all services have their own paths, so that you could provide wadl for those services.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following url and it should work, cxf has this ability to generate wadl itself.
 http://{IP}:{PORT}/{PROJECT-CONTEXT}/{CXF SERVLET CONTEXT}/?_wadl

for eg in my case it is `http://localhost:8080/demo-web/api/?_wadl`

Comment: I have done this but Iam getting dynamic sub resource for it.

Comment: your implementation classes are they annotated with JAX-RS annotations or do you make a decision in your top class with Path / and delegate the request to respective classes ?

Comment: make a decision in the top class with Path / and delegate the request to respective classes

Comment: i dont think cxf will be able to generate wadl for them since the implementation classes does not have jaxrs annotations

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of old, but it was driving me crazy.
If you are not returning an object as your subresource, this should do the trick:

```
JAXRSServerFactoryBean factory = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
factory.setStaticSubresourceResolution(true);
```

Just make sure to enable static subresource resolution before you set your service beans :)